# Can you extract information of hashed data in order to build a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset where most of the data, *except* for a timestamp, is hashed, and I have been asked to build a binary classifier using it. From my understanding, a (cryptographic) hashing function is built in such a way that is very difficult to reverse engineer its original value given the  hash. For example, an email or IP address, after a hash function is applied, would give a random key  and would not provide useful information.  So, how could I build a classifier when most of the information is hashed (and no longer related to the input values)?

Comment: One of the defining characteristics of a [cryptographic hash](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is that one would not "want an attacker to be able to learn anything useful about a message given only its digest ("hash values")." That would seem to settle the issue, apart from considerations of the quality of the hash being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you variables are categorical (nominal), then it doesn't matter whether the data is hashed or not, because the same input always generates the same hash number.

If your data is ordinal or cardinal, then it's a problem. With cardinal data you're almost completely out of luck. You can assume that hash code can't be reverse engineered. However, if you have limited number of inputs - such as integer numbers from 1 to 10 - you could map them manually to hash codes if the hash function is available. With continuous inputs, such as floating-point numbers, mapping to hash is very difficult. Especially, because there could be multiple hits to the same hash.

UPDATE

The simplest [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a function that returns 0 for any input. Yes, it's a valid hash function, because it satisfies the minimum requirements. It's fast, and it returns the same output given the same inputs, in other words it maps the input of potentially large and varying size to an output of fixed size. In this case the output size is 1, i.e. consists of one value, while the input can be anything, any number, object or entity. In some regards "return 0" is an ideal hash function :)

I gave this example to demonstrate that you really need to know something about your hash function, some properties in order to understand how much you can do in your situation.

A more practical example of hash function is CRC32 or MD5. They too return the same output to the same input. For instance, if your text content is (this site's IP address): `104.16.115.182` then [MD5](http://onlinemd5.com/) sum is always: `016931589A6F99FBF10153E94C4CBC8A`. The hash function is deterministic, as long as you're using the same hash function. If it weren't deterministic it would be useless for a typical use case of a hash function.

So, if you have something like an IP address, and use a popular hash function such as MD5, it's very unlikely that two IP addresses would have the same hash code if the number of IP addresses is not *too large*. That's not always the case though if you're using less popular hash functions, such the extreme one in my example `return 0`, which will always return the same code for any IP.

Comment: Do hash functions always generate the same hash number for a given input? Or they can assign the same hash number for two ore more inputs? I am using the hashed data in the context of building a binary classifier, but if the hash number of, say, an IP address associated with a hacker, can be given also to an IP from a safe user, then the hash number does not provide any significant information to discern between these two IPs and thus help the learning of the classifier. Is this right?